# asynchronous aiohttp requests send nothing, but synchronous requests succeed

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to get coin value on parasawp but the Async way does not work while the sync yes.
I've tried to remove ssl, wait betweens requests, limit TCP but in the end nothing worked correctly with async/aiohttp ...
I'm working on a old raspberry pi if it's useful.

[image]

here's my code :

```
async def get_price_as():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False, limit=8)) as session:
                    
        req_url = "https://apiv5.paraswap.io/prices/"
        param = {}
        param["srcDecimals"] = str(18)
        param["destDecimals"] = str(18)
        param["amount"] = str(10**18)
        
        for res in os.listdir(wu.chemin_cles):
            W3[res] = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(wu.url_provider[res]["rpc"]))
            clef_privee[res] = wu.cle_privee(res)
            param["network"] = wu.chain_ID(res)
            
            for a in adresses[res]:
                for b in adresses[res]:
                    if b!=a: 
                        param["srcToken"] = a
                        param["destToken"] = b
                        
                        async with session.get(req_url,params=param) as resp:
                            response = await resp.json(content_type=None)
                            
                            if response.get('priceRoute') == None:
                                print(res, " ", a, "/", b, " : ", response['error'])
                                c_1 += 1
                                r = paraswap.get_price(adresses[res][a], "18", adresses[res][b], "18", wu.chain_ID(res), str(10**18))
                                if r!=1:
                                    c_2+=1
                                    print(float(r["priceRoute"]["destAmount"])/10**18, "sync ...")
                            else : 
                                response = float(response["priceRoute"]["destAmount"])/10**18
                                print(res, " ", a, "/", b, " : ", response)
    
    
asyncio.run(get_price_as())



    # paraswap
def get_price(srcToken, srcDecimals, destToken, destDecimals, chainID, amount):
    req_url = "https://apiv5.paraswap.io/prices/"
    param = {}
    param["srcToken"] = srcToken
    param["srcDecimals"] = srcDecimals
    param["destToken"] = destToken
    param["destDecimals"] = destDecimals
    param["network"] = chainID
    param["amount"] = amount
    response = requests.get(req_url,params=param)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        return 1
```

it's not pretty yet but I just want something that work for now ... thx

Comment: `get_price_as` doesn’t return anything.